# ScrollView, zoom doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am creating an ios app using swift. In one of my ViewController, I have several UIView, each one responsible to show only a part of a picture (so I use a ScrollView, right?). I have subclass UIView to do that

```
import UIKit

    class LittlePicture: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    var image:UIImage!

    init(frame: CGRect, image:UIImage, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, zoom: CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        scrollView.frame = self.frame
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.addSubview(scrollView)

        setPhoto(image, x: x, y: y, zoom: zoom)

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setPhoto(image:UIImage,x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat,zoom:CGFloat){

        self.image = image

        scrollView.contentSize = image.size

        imageView.image = image
        imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: image.size)

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.001
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 100.0
        scrollView.zoomScale = zoom
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

}
```

Since the picture or the part of the picture to exhibit can change, I have implemented a function `setPhoto`. Problem is, when I call this function, ScrollView doesn't zoom anything (the scrollView.contentSize stays the same before and after calling scrollView.zoomScale = zoom)

In my UIViewController (it's just for the test...):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var l:LittlePicture!

    @IBAction func changePicture(sender:AnyObject){
        l.setPhoto(UIImage(named: "a.jpg")!, x: 0, y: 0, zoom: 0.05)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        l=LittlePicture(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300), image: UIImage(named: "a.jpg")!, x: 0, y: 0, zoom: 0.05)
        view.addSubview(l)
    }


}
```

When I click on the button, zoom get from 0.05 to 1.0. In fact, if I log scrollView.zoomScale, I obtain 0.05 but what I see on screen is a zoom equal to 1.0

Any idea? I am new at iOS development..

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this. Can you post the code you're using to initialize the `LittlePicture` instance?

Comment: Done. It's just something really basic to see if it works and it doesn't